# Minimum Xcode version to upload to App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store

I currently use Xcode7 and I have to continue using it for compatibility reasons. Should I expect that Xcode 7 will be incompatible with the App Store soon?

Answer (score 21):

The Xcode version changes once every year in April. Starting April 2023 you need to built with Xcode 14 and the iOS 16 SDK.

The updated documentation at https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/ says now:

> Please note, as of April 2023, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with a minimum of Xcode 14.1 and the iOS 16.1 SDK.

At the time of the question the documentation said:

> Please note that Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later […]

As iOS 12.1 SDK is included in Xcode 10.1, Xcode 7 seemed to be incompatible for new builds.

Comment: Then, minimum iOS deployment target for the App Store might be 8.0 now.

Comment: It's nice that you have included the history +1

Answer (score 11):

Starting April 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK.

For more details : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/

Comment: Looks like the link moved to: https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Answer (score 5):

> Starting April, 2020, all apps submitted to the App Store will need to
>   be built with Xcode 11. Xcode 11 requires macOS Mojave 10.14.3 or
>   later.

More you can find here:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/

Answer (score 3):

As of April 2022, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 13 ([source](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/)).

This information can be found directly in iTunes Connect where you can select the Build for your App. (At least it says so for iOS Apps)

(In 2017, you needed Xcode 6 (or newer) or Application Loader 3 (or newer).)

---

Though the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html) says that the only way to ensure your Xcode configuration will be accepted is to "Validate" your build:

> For compatibility reasons, the App Store will often accept apps that are built with some older versions of Xcode or Base SDK.
>
> To determine if an older Xcode configuration is currently accepted by the App Store, you can choose "Archive" under the "Product" menu to make an archived build, then use the Validate feature, to test if that build meets minimum requirements for submission to the App Store.

Comment: thanks, we are still talking about 6 i see, so i can stay easy about 7?

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni I found no information when your app is allowed to be build with an "old" Xcode version. The safest way to find out would be to use the validate feature.

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni were you able to submit with Xcode 7 build in the end?

Comment: @MohamedHafez no, i'm not working more at that project

Answer (score 0):

> Starting April 2022, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 13 and the iOS 15 SDK.

For more detail : https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Comment: This "Xcode 13 require ... and M1" is false. Xcode 13 runs just fine on an Intel mac. I'm using it right this moment.

Comment: What are you quoting when you quote "Xcode 13 require ... and M1"?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that as of **April 2024** all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with a minimum of **Xcode 15 and the iOS 17 SDK**.

[https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/#:~:text=Build%20with%20Xcode%2015&text=Build%20your%20apps%20using%20the,and%20the%20iOS%2017%20SDK](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/#:%7E:text=Build%20with%20Xcode%2015&text=Build%20your%20apps%20using%20the,and%20the%20iOS%2017%20SDK).