# Installing Older Version of Firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I use  Xcode 9.4  and the firebase I installed can't work on the version of Xcode I'm using. I can't run Xcode 10.1 because the simulator lags and slows down my system. it basically doesn't work at all ! So Xcode 9.4 is my best bet

How do I install an older version of Firebase with cocoa pods?  Thanks for the Help !

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to specify the version of Firebase you need to install

My best guess will be something like this

```
pod 'Firebase', '4.4.0'
```

Where

> '4.4.0'

is the version of the Firebase.

For more specific info on the Firebase versions check [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios)

Comment: You can specify a previous version of a pod, but I will highly recommend you to update to a newer Xcode because in 9.4 you can only use swift 3 or 4. Also, you won't be able to push your app to App Store as it requires iOS 12.1 SDK https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251905/1797194 and it isn't guaranteed that old firebase version will work